# Attaching files files to line spacing in email (RTF) with win32com

Tags: python, win32com

I'm making a tool for automatic email with Python and win32com.
I would like to attach files in line spacing due to make mail in RTF.

**Accomplishment**

```
Hello, world!
{attached file}
Thank you.
```

**Code**

```
outlook =  = win32com.client.Dispatch("Outlook.Application")
mail = outlook.createItemFromTemplate(template_item)

mail.to = ""
mail.cc = ""
mail.bcc = ""
mail.bodyformat = 3 # 3: RTF
mail.Attachment.Add(attachment)
mail.Display(True)
```

With this code, All files were attached to bottom.
I handled with using 'format' method in mail.Body, but the name of file was inserted.

Could you teach me about the approach to attach files to line spacing in email (RTF)?

Answer (score 0):

```
mail.to = ""
mail.cc = ""
mail.bcc = ""
mail.bodyformat = 3
mail.Display(True) # before attachment
mail.Attachment.Add(Source=attachment,Position=position)
```

Changing the "Display" layout, I can attach files in line spacing.